# how to move BigQuery data to long term storage? Or is just automatically branded as so after 90 days?

Tags: google-bigquery

How to move BigQuery data to long term storage?

How to move the historic data to long-term storage in Google Cloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you do not update table (or partition) within 90 days  - it is "automatically" (no needs to move anything) assigned as a long-term data - and charged respectively

Comment: Thanks all! It was really helpful knowing this. It was little confusing to begin with.

Comment: I am not able to understand your answer for a partitioned table (May be I haven't understand BigQuery internals). Lets take I have a partitioned table which has data for every day partition starting from Jan-01-2017 to Jan-21-2019 and assume whole table was not updated more than 90 days. Now I am updating the recent 10 days partition (Jan-11-2019 to Jan-21-2019), whether the whole table(750 partition) will be moved to active storage or only 10 days partition will be moved to active storage? 
(For my understanding, every partition belongs to different file, thats the reason for my confusion)

Comment: Hi @mikhail just bumping this again, for my above question. Would be great if you are able to help me to understand the same scenario for the partitioned table concept.

Comment: In your case, only 10 days partition will be considered active, while the rest remains in long term storage. See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#storage

Answer (score 2):

[From the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#long-term-storage):

> If a table is not edited for 90 consecutive days, the price of storage
>   for that table automatically drops by 50 percent to $0.01 per GB per
>   month.
>
> There is no degradation of performance, durability, availability, or
>   any other functionality when a table is considered long term storage.
>
> If the table is edited, the price reverts back to the regular storage
>   pricing of $0.02 per GB per month, and the 90-day timer starts
>   counting from zero.
>
> Anything that modifies the data in a table resets the timer (load,
>   copy to, query with destination table)

Comment: Thanks, it was very helpful!